# How to customize a label in a Vaadin Gridlayout

Tags: css, vaadin, grid-layout

I am working with a 5x4 vaadin grid layout. 
I am trying to add two customized labels in a grid. I am using .scss for styling. I am not able get the label filled in whole.  No matter i set the height and width of my label to 100%. It does not fill whole. I have attached a .png how i need the outcome.

Things i have tried.

```
_Layout = new GridLayout(5,4);
_Layout.setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
_Layout.setHeight(23, UNITS_CM);
_Layout.setSizeFull();
_Layout.setSpacing(true);
_Layout.addStyleName("grid");

_Name = new Label("");
_Name.setSizeFull();
_Name.setWidth("100px");
_Name.setHeight("100%");
_Name.addStyleName("label");
```

In my .scss i have something like.

```
.label {
    color: black;
     background-color: lightblue;
     text-align: center;
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     font-size: 80px;
     text-align: center;
    }

.grid {
    display:grid;
    height: 10px;
    grid-gap: 10px 40px;
    grid-template-rows: 50px;
    }
```

But it does not fill one block. Please find the attachment. Thank you.

Comment: Why `_Layout.setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);`and `_Layout.setHeight(23, UNITS_CM);`and then telling it to be fullsize? `_Layout.setSizeFull();`

Comment: Attached png? :)

Comment: Answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46342417